# Android Java - setVolume past max 1.0f

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, volume

I'm using mediaplayer to set my volumes. I understand 0.0f is silent and 1.0f is full volume. Is there any way I can get the music to play louder than it's 100% volume programmatically?

```
 mPlayer.setVolume(2.0f, 2.0f);
```

Seems to just keep it still at 1.0f volume

Comment: While I don't know much about Android specifically, this may not be a good idea. Many digital audio formats quite literally have a maximum amplitude and increasing the amplitude any louder results in clipping or overflow.

Comment: Why do you want to bypass my default settings and make me deaf?

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Haha, because each song I imported into my app play at different volumes so this is my ghetto way of equalizing everything

Answer (score 0):

If 1.0 is full volume, then 2.0 is the same as 1.0

If they were different, then 1.0 would not be the full volume.

In other words, I'm pretty sure it's not possible to do that.

Answer (score 0):

1.0 is full volume and going over it will not change anything